# Why does the all the generated populations becomes the same?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

So I am making genetic algorithms where the fittest chromosome is the one that is all ones [1,1,1,1...]. I coded the whole thing below while debugging I found that crossover, mutation, generate_population works and I went through the code for my other functions and they all make sense. But whenever I run it I find that after the second or third generation all my other generations are the same. so my questions are that why is that happening because I went through my code and every new generation should have a different and "fitter" population and there should be variety among each population. Any help would be really appreciated. [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxzFc.png)

```
import random

def generate_population(size):
    population = []
    for i in range(size):
        individual = []
        for g in range(64):
          x = random.randrange(0,2)
          individual.append(x)
        population.append(individual)
    return population

def fitnessFunc(individual):
  fit = 0
  for i in individual:
    if i == 1:
      fit += 1
    else:
      fit = fit 
  return fit


def choice_by_roulette(sorted_population, fitness_sum):
    offset = 0
    normalized_fitness_sum = fitness_sum
    lowest_fitness = fitnessFunc(sorted_population[0])
    if lowest_fitness < 0:
        offset = lowest_fitness
        normalized_fitness_sum += offset * len(sorted_population)

    draw = random.uniform(0, 1)

    accumulated = 0
    for individual in sorted_population:
        fitness = fitnessFunc(individual)+offset
        probability = fitness / normalized_fitness_sum
        accumulated += probability

        if draw <= accumulated:
            return individual

def sort_population_by_fitness(population):
    return sorted(population, key=fitnessFunc)

def crossover(individual_a, individual_b):
  for i in range(64):
    pop = random.randint(1,2)
    if pop == 1:
      individual_a[i] = individual_b[i]
    else:
      individual_a = individual_a
  return individual_a

def mutate(individual):
    rand = random.randrange(0,10)
    if rand == 5:
      if individual[rand]==1:
        individual[rand]=0
      else:
        individual[rand]=1
    return individual

def make_next_generation(previous_population):
    next_generation = []
    sorted_by_fitness_population = sort_population_by_fitness(previous_population)
    population_size = len(previous_population)
    fitness_sum = sum(fitnessFunc(individual) for individual in population)
    for i in range(population_size):
        choice = choice_by_roulette(sorted_by_fitness_population, fitness_sum)
        schoice = choice_by_roulette(sorted_by_fitness_population, fitness_sum)
        if choice != None:
          first_choice = choice
        if schoice != None:
          second_choice = schoice
        individual = crossover(first_choice, second_choice)
        individual = mutate(individual)
        next_generation.append(individual)
    return next_generation


population = generate_population(size=10)
generations = 1000

i = 1
while True:
    print(f" GENERATION {i}")

    for individual in population:
        print(individual, fitnessFunc(individual))
    if i == generations:
        break
    i += 1
    population = make_next_generation(population)

best_individual = sort_population_by_fitness(population)[-1]
print(" FINAL RESULT")
print(best_individual, fitnessFunc(best_individual))
```

Comment: It looks like you're expecting function arguments and return values to be copies. That's not how Python works. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: is there a specific line in the code that you are referring to?

Comment: `crossover` mutates and returns one of its inputs, for example.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: Yes, I added an image of the result after the 1000 generation. As you can see all the individuals in the population is the same which shouldn't be and all the precious populations are also the same

Comment: Sorry, I meant the previous populations which are all the same after 3 generations. So my questions are that why is that happening because I went through my code and every new generation should have a different and "fitter" population and there should be variety among each population.

Answer (score 0):

I found three major problems. Will try to break it down, but since I'm not completely sure what intended result is, it's hard to say for sure how it should be done.

Problem 1: Crossover function mutates parent generation "in place" while creating next generation. That means ~ 25 % of one parents genes will mutate towards other parents gene set.

Problem 2: make_next_generation() does not make sure two different individuals are sent to crossover. That will sometimes result in individuals passing over unchanged to the next generation.

Problem 3: mutate(individual) only affects one gene out of 64. (Guessing not on purpose)

```
import random


def generate_individual():
    # Use list comprehensions
    return [random.randrange(0,2) for g in range(64)]


def generate_population(size):
    # Same result, only less code
    return [generate_individual() for i in range(size)]

def fitnessFunc(individual):
  # Yes, this line does the same work.
  return sum(individual)
  # fit = 0
  # for i in individual:
  #   if i == 1:
  #     fit += 1
  # The following two lines did nothing
  #   else:
  #     fit = fit 
  # return fit
```

There is a real problem in choice_by_roulette(). Don't know how it's supposed to work, though. Commented below.

```
def choice_by_roulette(sorted_population, fitness_sum):
    offset = 0
    normalized_fitness_sum = fitness_sum
    lowest_fitness = fitnessFunc(sorted_population[0])
    # Lower than 0? fitnessFunc() will never return that.
    # Could it be lowest_fitness > 0?
    if lowest_fitness < 0:
        offset = lowest_fitness
        normalized_fitness_sum += offset * len(sorted_population)

    draw = random.random()

    accumulated = 0
    for individual in sorted_population:
        fitness = fitnessFunc(individual)+offset
        probability = fitness / normalized_fitness_sum
        accumulated += probability

        if draw <= accumulated:
            return individual

def sort_population_by_fitness(population):
    return sorted(population, key=fitnessFunc)
```

Crossover should not mutate old individuals(?). Since the same individuals may get picked more than once, they will have mutated ~ 50 % towards another individual within the same generation. This is probably your biggest issue.

```
def crossover(individual_a, individual_b):
  for i in range(64):
    pop = random.randint(1,2)
    if pop == 1:
      individual_a[i] = individual_b[i]
    else:
      individual_a = individual_a
  return individual_a
```

My suggestion:

```
def crossover(individual_a, individual_b):
  return [random.choice(genes) for genes in zip(individual_a, individual_b)]
```

Here you don't need to return anything. You're literally mutating individual in place. Also, only gene 5 can mutate, but maybe that's supposed to be?

```
def mutate(individual):
    rand = random.randrange(0,10)
    if rand == 5:
      individual[rand] = 1 - individual[rand]  # Toggle: 1-0=1, 1-1=0
      # if individual[rand]==1:
      #   individual[rand]=0
      # else:
      #   individual[rand]=1

def make_next_generation(previous_population):
    next_generation = []
    sorted_by_fitness_population = sort_population_by_fitness(previous_population)
    population_size = len(previous_population)
    fitness_sum = sum(fitnessFunc(individual) for individual in population)
    for i in range(population_size):
        choice = choice_by_roulette(sorted_by_fitness_population, fitness_sum)
        schoice = choice_by_roulette(sorted_by_fitness_population, fitness_sum)
        # This code will not work. first_choice will be user without being declared below if any of there are None.
        # if choice != None:
        #   first_choice = choice
        # if schoice != None:
        #   second_choice = schoice
        # choice and schoice will sometimes be the same individual. That will definitely diminish the genetic diversity.
        while choice == schoice:
            schoice = choice_by_roulette(sorted_by_fitness_population, fitness_sum)
        individual = crossover(choice, schoice)
        mutate(individual)
        next_generation.append(individual)
    return next_generation


population = generate_population(size=10)
generations = 1000

for i in range(1, generations+1):
    print(f" GENERATION {i}")
    for individual in population:
        print(individual, fitnessFunc(individual))
    population = make_next_generation(population)

best_individual = sort_population_by_fitness(population)[-1]
print(" FINAL RESULT")
print(best_individual, fitnessFunc(best_individual))
```

Comment: So in my Crossover function is supposed to work by going through the two parent chromosomes and to make the child, it will randomly choose one of the genes from the two parents. Mutation works by randomly flipping one gene in the child chromosome for every 20 or so population.

Comment: The choice_by_roulette basically is like a pie and it gives the chromosomes with the highest fitness score a bigger portion of the pie and then we randomly choose a point in the pie and choose the corresponding chromosome as a parent.

Comment: The problem with the original crossover() is that it not only generated a child, it also changed 50 % of one parents genes to match the other parent. That parent then might get chosen again, but now with the changed genes, passing on those to one more child, and possibly to another parent.

Comment: And for choice_by_roulette() I think you should just change **if lowest_fitness < 0:** to **if lowest_fitness:**.